# How to fix "Input shape axis 0 must equal 4, got shape [5]" in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am running tensorflow object_detection api in a docker with TiTAN. Using the command `python object_detection/model_main.py --"pipeline_config_path object_detection/train_manhole/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config --model_dir object_detection/train_manhole --alsologtostder`, I receive an error.

Here is the error information:

```
root@a358c8644e9c:~/manhole/models/research# python object_detection/model_main.py --pipeline_config_path object_detection/train_manhole/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config --model_dir object_detection/train_manhole --alsologtostder
/root/manhole/models/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py:26: UserWarning: 
This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already
been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

The backend was *originally* set to 'TkAgg' by the following code:
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 26, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib
  File "/root/manhole/models/research/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "/root/manhole/models/research/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 28, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import coco_evaluation
  File "/root/manhole/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_evaluation.py", line 20, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import coco_tools
  File "/root/manhole/models/research/object_detection/metrics/coco_tools.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pycocotools import coco
  File "/root/manhole/models/research/pycocotools/coco.py", line 49, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 71, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    line for line in traceback.format_stack()


  import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')  # pylint: disable=multiple-statements
WARNING:tensorflow:Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (<function create_model_fn.<locals>.model_fn at 0x7f0a65a25e18>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /root/manhole/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:80: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(...)`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py:1165: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /root/manhole/models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py:152: batch_and_drop_remainder (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.batching) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.batch(..., drop_remainder=True)`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /root/manhole/models/research/object_detection/predictors/heads/box_head.py:93: calling reduce_mean (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with keep_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From /root/manhole/models/research/object_detection/core/losses.py:345: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow
into the labels input on backprop by default.

See `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2`.

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:112: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
2019-03-29 02:38:24.469848: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-03-29 02:38:24.546573: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:964] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-03-29 02:38:24.547117: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: TITAN Xp major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 11.91GiB freeMemory: 11.41GiB
2019-03-29 02:38:24.547150: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-03-29 02:38:24.709319: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-03-29 02:38:24.709370: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2019-03-29 02:38:24.709377: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2019-03-29 02:38:24.709670: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 11036 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: TITAN Xp, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input shape axis 0 must equal 4, got shape [5]
     [[{{node Preprocessor/ResizeToRange/cond/resize_images/unstack}} = Unpack[T=DT_INT32, axis=0, num=4, _device="/device:CPU:0"](Preprocessor/ResizeToRange/cond/resize_images/Shape)]]
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext}} = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[1], [1,?,?,3], [1,2], [1,3], [1,100], [1,100,4], [1,100,2], [1,100,2], [1,100], [1,100], [1,100], [1]], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](IteratorV2)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 109, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/model_main.py", line 105, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 471, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 610, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/training.py", line 711, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 354, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1207, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1241, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1471, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 671, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1156, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1255, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1240, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1312, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1076, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1328, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1348, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input shape axis 0 must equal 4, got shape [5]
     [[{{node Preprocessor/ResizeToRange/cond/resize_images/unstack}} = Unpack[T=DT_INT32, axis=0, num=4, _device="/device:CPU:0"](Preprocessor/ResizeToRange/cond/resize_images/Shape)]]
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at object_detection/model_main.py:105)  = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[1], [1,?,?,3], [1,2], [1,3], [1,100], [1,100,4], [1,100,2], [1,100,2], [1,100], [1,100], [1,100], [1]], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](IteratorV2)]]
```

My docker environment is :

```
== cat /etc/issue ===============================================
Linux a358c8644e9c 4.15.0-46-generic #49~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 17:45:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial

== are we in docker =============================================
Yes

== compiler =====================================================
c++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


== uname -a =====================================================
Linux a358c8644e9c 4.15.0-46-generic #49~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 12 17:45:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

== check pips ===================================================
numpy                1.14.2                
protobuf             3.7.1                 
tensorflow-estimator 1.13.0                
tensorflow-gpu       1.12.0                

== check for virtualenv =========================================
False

== tensorflow import ============================================
tf.VERSION = 1.12.0
tf.GIT_VERSION = v1.12.0-0-ga6d8ffae09
tf.COMPILER_VERSION = 4.8.5
Sanity check: array([1], dtype=int32)

== env ==========================================================
LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is unset

== nvidia-smi ===================================================
Fri Mar 29 02:57:43 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.78       Driver Version: 410.78       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  TITAN Xp            Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 23%   36C    P0    69W / 250W |    378MiB / 12192MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

== cuda libs  ===================================================
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.9.0.176
/usr/local/cuda-9.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart_static.a
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you post the MetaGraphDefs of the saved_model.pb and the shape of the input you are trying to feed the model?

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it. The reason was these were some datasets which were pictures broken. What's more, the depth of some pictures had more than 3. I used the python script to select those pictures which caused the error above. Finally, it runs normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! I fixed it. The reason was these were some datasets which were pictures broken. What's more, the depth of some pictures had more than 3. I used the python script to select those pictures which caused the error above. Finally, it runs normally.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, the problem was because of the dataset(broken images in the dataset). There were incorrect image shapes like 2D image shapes in the dataset, that the correct shape should be 3D shape.

What was solved is deleting the not 3D images by comparing images' shapes. Done!!!!